# how to combine some for loops for i,j in v1,v2

Tags: python, python-3.x

My goal is to combine some for loops.

for example,

```
v1=[1,2]
v2=[6,7]

for i,j in v1,v2:
    print(i)
    print(j)
```

It should be printed:

```
1
6
2
7
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) here:

```
v1=[1,2]
v2=[6,7]

for i,j in zip(v1,v2):
    print(i)
    print(j)
```

Comment: Assumes the lists are of the same length, anyway the dupe target provides a more complete answer

Answer (score -1):

You can go:

```
for i in range(len(v1)): # Assuming both v1 and v2 are the same length.
    print(v1[i])
    print(v2[i])
```

Hope it helps.